# Create a Mongo query in Java using a String

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongomapper, bson

Mongo Java driver provides a `JSON.parse(String query)` method to convert query into `DBObject`.

```
public void find() {
    DBObject query = JSON.parse("{name:{$exists:true}}");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
}
```

Using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) objects can be un/marshalled the same way:

```
DBCollection collection = new Mongo().getDB("db").getCollection("friends");

public void save() {
    DBObject document = jsonMarshall(new Friend("John", 24));
    collection.save(document);
    // db.peoples.save({name: 'John', age: 24})
}

ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

public DBObject jsonMarshall(Object obj) throws Exception {
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    jsonMapper.writer().writeValue(writer, obj);
    return (DBObject) JSON.parse(writer.toString());
}
```

Fortunately, the library [bson4jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) allows objects to be un/marshalled with Jackson without the need of `JSON.parse(String)`:

```
public void save() {
    DBObject document = bsonMarshall(new Friend("John", 24));
    collection.save(document);
    // db.peoples.save({name: 'John', age: 24})
}

ObjectMapper bsonMapper = new ObjectMapper(new BsonFactory());

public DBObject bsonMarshall(Object obj) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bsonMapper.writer().writeValue(output, obj);
    return new LazyWriteableDBObject(output.toByteArray(), new LazyBSONCallback());
}
```

But, unfortunately, this technique do not seems to work with queries.
Is there a way to use bson4jackson to marshall a String to a DBObject? Like:

```
public void find() {
    DBObject query = bsonMarshall("{name:{$exists:true}}");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this library help you ? http://jongo.org/

Comment: @Louisa Your answer is funny: I'm the co-writer of this Java library ;-) And, for the moment on, Jongo uses `JSON.parse()` for query marshalling. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @yvesamsellem slight side note; is Jongo still being updated? Seems to be no official release alongside Mongo 3.x?

Comment: @zackehh Jongo is still updated but at a slower pace now, because the feature list match our needs. If you got a specific feature in mind, go ahead and create a github issue (or better, a pull request).