# How to run a mongo query from java program?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-shell, mongo-java-driver

The query that we run from a mongo-shell, I want to run the same query from a java program. How can I do that?

Comment: Why use the shell from Java when you have proper bindings?

Comment: I think he is saying that he wrote some SQL query, it runs in the console (thus it's valid SQL etc) and now he wants to use the java bindings.

Comment: @Hubert Grzeskowiak, I have a plugin that take queries from mysql/oracle/cassandra etc and run into configured db dynamically. All the db configurations and the query to run is stored in data base. I want to enhance this plugin to support Mongo DB as well.

Comment: The shell is probably only a wrapper around some libraries. If you need the functionality in your application/plugin, you probably want to use the same libraries instead of the user-oriented shell

Comment: I had the same question I know how mongo works, but I was wondering too how you can run the same query that you develop/test via the shell in a program to ease debugging, sadly the answer seems to be you cannot, but this is still a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is mentioned in the comment in the answer to [Create a Mongo query in Java using a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788957/create-a-mongo-query-in-java-using-a-string) in that the library Jongo is what you are looking for.  See http://jongo.org/ .  Looks like not 100% the same e.g. db.collection.find(QUERY) becomes friends.find(QUERY) where query is a string.  But it is closer than making the entire query into a DBObject.